# Flexible application configuration in C++

Tags: c++, configuration, configuration-files, factory, factory-pattern

I am developing a C++ application used to simulate a real world scenario. Based on this simulation our team is going to develop, test and evaluate different algorithms working within such a real world scenrio.

We need the possibility to define several scenarios (they might differ in a few parameters, but a future scenario might also require creating objects of new classes) and the possibility to maintain a set of algorithms (which is, again, a set of parameters but also the definition which classes are to be created). Parameters are passed to the classes in the constructor.

I am wondering which is the best way to manage all the scenario and algorithm configurations. It should be easily possible to have one developer work on one scenario with "his" algorithm and another developer working on another scenario with "his" different algorithm. Still, the parameter sets might be huge and should be "sharable" (if I defined a set of parameters for a certain algorithm in Scenario A, it should be possible to use the algorithm in Scenario B without copy&paste).

It seems like there are two main ways to accomplish my task:

- Define a configuration file format that can handle my requirements. This format might be XML based or custom. As there is no C#-like reflection in C++, it seems like I have to update the config-file parser each time a new algorithm class is added  to project (in order to convert a string like "MyClass" into a new instance of MyClass). I could create a name for every setup and pass this name as command line argument.

  - The pros are: no compilation required to change a parameter and re-run, I can easily store the whole config file with the simulation results
  - contra: seems like a lot of effort, especially hard because I am using a lot of template classes that have to be instantiated with given template arguments. No IDE support for writing the file (at least without creating a whole XSD which I would have to update everytime a parameter/class is added)
- Wire everything up in C++ code. I am not completely sure how I would do this to separate all the different creation logic but still be able to reuse parameters across scenarios. I think I'd also try to give every setup a (string) name and use this name to select the setup via command line arg.

  - pro: type safety, IDE support, no parser needed
  - con: how can I easily store the setup with the results (maybe some serialization?)?, needs compilation after every parameter change

Now here are my questions:
 - What is your opinion? Did I miss
   important pros/cons? 
 - did I miss a third option?
 - Is there a simple way to implement the config file approach that gives
   me enough flexibility?
 - How would you organize all the factory code in the seconde approach?  Are there any good C++ examples for  something like this out there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: From my personal experience, parsing a configuration file tends to become far more complex than hard-coding every scenario in the C++ binary. This language simply lacks easy dynamic reflection (and serialization) to let the user control algorithm flow in a straightforward manner – as of now, at least.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found [this website](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/subscription_problem.html) with a nice template supporting factory which I think will be used in my code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this without templates or reflection.

First, you make sure that all the classes you want to create from the configuration file have a common base class. Let's call this `MyBaseClass` and assume that `MyClass1`, `MyClass2` and `MyClass3` all inherit from it.

Second, you implement a factory function for each of `MyClass1`, `MyClass2` and `MyClass3`. The signatures of all these factory functions must be identical. An example factory function is as follows.

```
MyBaseClass * create_MyClass1(Configuration & cfg)
{
  // Retrieve config variables and pass as parameters
  // to the constructor
  int age = cfg->lookupInt("age");
  std::string address = cfg->lookupString("address");
  return new MyClass1(age, address);
}
```

Third, you register all the factory functions in a map.

`typedef MyBaseClass* (*FactoryFunc)(Configuration *);
std::map<std::string, FactoryFunc> nameToFactoryFunc;
nameToFactoryFunc["MyClass1"] = &create_MyClass1;
nameToFactoryFunc["MyClass2"] = &create_MyClass2;
nameToFactoryFunc["MyClass3"] = &create_MyClass3;`

Finally, you parse the configuration file and iterate over it to find all the entries that specify the name of a class. When you find such an entry, you look up its factory function in the `nameToFactoryFunc` table and invoke the function to create the corresponding object.

Comment: By implementing the `create_*` functions with the same signature and different return type you basically did the job of the templates by hand. I don't say it's bad but I think it'd be clearer if you used one templated `create` function and specialized it for every subtype.

Comment: The decision about which template function to call is made at compile time. In contrast, the use of a _name->factory function_ map enables that decision to be made at runtime, so it is a form of polymorphism.

Comment: At compile time happens only the type deduction - you can still hold pointers to templated functions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641657/address-of-c-template-function

Comment: I have to admit that I couldn't create a map of specializations of a function template. It seems these functions have different types despite the same signature and return type.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's not as flexible as one would hope. Everytime someone wants to add a new behavior, that dev needs to understand this factory implementation, class relations, and then finally customize the code. Sometimes the class relations don't allow what is needed, in which case their OOP model failed, requiring an overhaul. Also, the code position of the factory code is most likely distant from the actual algorithm.

Comment: @Dean I agree with your critique but prefer to think of it as a "limitation" or "drawback" of the approach rather than a "problem". Some simple documentation could be written to illustrate how to write the necessary infrastructure code to support use of a new class, and (in "design patterns" terminology) an adapter class could be used to connect the infrastructure code to the pure-model class.

Comment: @Dean if you want to read some details about the approach I advocate, then I recommend you visit www.config4star.org (a config-file parser I wrote), read Chapters 2 & 3 of the "Getting Started Guide" to get an overview of the syntax and API, and then look at parts II and III of the "Practical Usage Guide". I am not claiming this approach is a silver bullet, but I have found it useful often enough to keep it in the toolbox of techniques that I use occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use XML, it's possible that boost::spirit could short-circuit at least some of the problems you are facing.  Here's a simple [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html) of how config data could be parsed directly into a class instance.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I haven't seen this before and it looks pretty good for having parameters in config files, but it still seems like a lot of work to get my template arguments in...