# Template function cast: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information

Tags: c++, linux, mingw

I'm trying to get a third party's library source code to compile on mingw in codeblocks on Lubuntu, when I encounter "address of overloaded function with no contextual type information".

As it's a third party library it's not possible for me to produce a small example, so here are the definitions:

```
namespace priv
{
    template <typename T> SoundFileReader* createReader() {return new T;}
    template <typename T> SoundFileWriter* createWriter() {return new T;}
}
```

And the error occurs in the function:

```
template <typename T>
void SoundFileFactory::unregisterReader()
{
    for (ReaderFactoryArray::iterator it = s_readers.begin(); it != s_readers.end(); )
    {
        if (it->create == &priv::createReader<T>) //Error occurs here
            it = s_readers.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }
}
```

create from what I can see is a function pointer:

```
struct ReaderFactory
{
    bool (*check)(InputStream&);
    SoundFileReader* (*create)();
};
```

The error states:

```
address of overloaded function with no contextual type information
```

From what I can determine it's trying to compare the pointer address of a template function to a stored address held in memory, and the compiler cannot resolve the template function address, but I cannot understand why as there appears to be only one declaration of said function.

Searching online regarding the problem offers no insights as all of the example pieces of code are different to this situation and I have little idea what is occurring so I cannot fix it by myself.

What has gone wrong and how to do I fix it?

**Update:**

I've since pulled together some code that replicates the effect:

```
class VagueClass
{
    int A;
};

class VagueFactory
{
    public:
    VagueClass* (*create)();
};

namespace priv
{
    template <typename T> VagueClass* VagueFunction() {return new T;}
}

template<typename T>
void RandomFunction()
{
    VagueFactory VagueVariable;

    if(VagueVariable.create == &priv::VagueFunction<T>)
    {
        //Some message here
    }
}

int main()
{
    RandomFunction<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it will [come down to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641657/address-of-c-template-function). The short answer is it seems like the compiler is treating the template function as an overload of all valid types rather than a proper template. From the answers on the page, you might do with a cast to the relevant function pointer type, or a `decltype` / `typedef`, it appears to be compiler-dependent as well.

Comment: The example code won't compile [tested here](https://ideone.com/D0rkMP) -  `error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'VagueClass*' in return
     template <typename T> VagueClass* VagueFunction() {return new T;}` - on gcc 5.1 this works using `class VagueClassDerived : public VagueClass {}; ` and making a call using that type as the argument, but 4.3.2 gcc confirms the error - `In function 'void RandomFunction() [with T = VagueClassDerived]':  error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information`